# How to make non-greedy selection with OR operator?

Tags: regex

I wrote a line which makes what I want:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)\/$

https://coinmarketcap.com/
https://www.buzzfeed.com/
https://www.refinery29.com/
https://www.businessinsider.com/
```

How can I make the same selection but instead of [a-zA-Z0-9] select anything that starts from // or .?

Comment: Is lookbehind allowed?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, yes, lookbehind allowed.

Comment: Then just lookbehind for `\.` or `//` at the beginning of the pattern

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I don't know how to implement lookbehind  here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
(?<=\/\/|\.)[^.]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\/$
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\/\/|\.)` --> Look behind to ensure the text is preceded by either a `//` or `.`
- `[^.]+` --> Captures anything except dot
- `\.` -->  Folowed by a literal dot
- `[a-zA-Z]+\/` --> Followed by one or more letters and a `/`
- `$` --> End of string

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MpttxP/1)**